# Overlapping css

Tags: html, css

I am a 3 month beginner. I'm currently working on a simple game, to try different skills I learned recently and I have a problem I couldn't solve with Google.

My JS code generates a grid made out of divs, (coordinates in ID), and appends a child (the player) once they're here, but I can't get to display the player image. I previously just gave the div a #player id but I changed and tried appending the player as a child div, because later it'll be easier to move a div around rather than removing and adding IDs (when making player controls).

Here's my code:

The CSS

```
.tile{
margin:2px;
height:50px;
width:50px;
border:1px solid black;
display: inline-block;
}
#map{
height:482px;
width:730px;
background-image:url(bg.png);
}
#player{
background-image:url(player.png);
}
#monster{
background-image:url(monster.png);
}
#start{
margin:auto;
color:white;
background-color:grey;
border:2px solid black;
}
```

The JavaScript

```
var game = function(){
$("#hgrass").hide()
$("#htile").hide()
$("#hmnstr").hide()
$("#hplayr").hide()
$("#start").click(function(){startGame();
});

var genMap = function(){
    var map = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(map);
    map.setAttribute("id","map")
    for(c=0;c<8;c++){
        for(r = 0;r<13;r++){
            var tile = document.createElement("div");
            var tileId = c+"/"+r;
            tile.setAttribute("id",tileId);
            tile.setAttribute("class","tile");
            map.appendChild(tile);
        }
    }

}
var spawnPlayer = function(){
    var rrow = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 8))); 
    var rcol = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 13)));
    var prow = rrow.toString(); 
    var pcol = rcol.toString();
    var coord = document.getElementById(prow+"/"+pcol)
    var player = document.createElement("div")
    player.setAttribute("id","player")
    coord.appendChild(player)
}
var spawnMonster = function(){
    var rrow = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 8))); 
    var rcol = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 13)));
    var prow = rrow.toString(); 
    var pcol = rcol.toString();
    var monster = document.getElementById(prow+"/"+pcol)
    monster.setAttribute("id","monster")
}
/*var turns = function(){
    var pturn = true

        $(document).keypress(function(event){
                var pla = document.getElementById("player")
                if (event.which == 37){
                    pla.removeAttribute("id","player");
                    pturn = false;
                }   
            });
    };*/

var startGame = function(){
genMap();
spawnPlayer();
spawnMonster();
// turns();
$("#start").hide()
$("#hgrass").show()
$("#htile").show()
$("#hmnstr").show()
$("#hplayr").show()
}
};
```

And the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="game()">
<button type="button" id="start">Click to start</button>
<button type="button" id="hgrass">Click to hide grass
<button type="button" id="htile">Click to hide tiles</button>
<button type="button" id="hmnstr">Click to hide monster</button>
<button type="button" id="hplayr">Click to hide player</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: supply the js code?

Comment: I don't really know what you are doing, a working example would be very helpful (e.g. [JS FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)). But have you ever heard of `position:absolute;`

Comment: js is there (forgot to add it) yeah i've tried with positions and z-index but to no visible result, and the weird thing is that the player div does exist, i saw it with firebug in the html, but i cant see it displayed, when even the parent div is actually just a 1px black border(so the center is invisible)

Comment: Just a tip: Try learning canvas instead of playing around with divs and other elements.

Comment: You should check what the *real* DOM says, ie the DOM once the player DOM element got spawned (if no JS error occurred before).

Comment: well, i just learned what that is( more or less) but i really have no clue as to how to find anything in there, most of the components i can't even tell where they're from ^^ if you could point me to where i can find the html in it's last state i'd be grateful :) (i almost started with canvas but i really want to do this from scratch first just for curiosity's sake)

Comment: You're applying the monster image differently than the player image. Is there a reason for that? The monster image shows up. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5npaf0vz/).